# Shortcutting script, touch function

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to have a better/shorter way to decrease any lag and use less effort, as if I need to change anything in the script, I'll need to do it for each one.

Is there a better way of having short?

I tried having them the "Glass1's" the same name and the "Glass2's" the same name, but it worked on the first one only, I wish I clarified it.

Here is my code:

```lua
local End = script.Parent.End
local Start = script.Parent.Start
local Glass = script.Parent

--Glass1/1-8 are the glasses that fall if touched and they change color to red

local function TouchedGlass11(hit)
    local partParent = hit.Parent
    local humanoid = partParent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        local num = Glass.Glass11
        num.Anchored = false
        num.BrickColor = BrickColor.Red()
        wait(2)
        num:Destroy()
    else return
    end
end

Glass.Glass11.Touched:Connect(TouchedGlass11)

local function TouchedGlass12(hit)
    local partParent = hit.Parent
    local humanoid = partParent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        local num = Glass.Glass12
        num.Anchored = false
        num.BrickColor = BrickColor.Red()
        wait(2)
        num:Destroy()
    else return
    end
end

Glass.Glass12.Touched:Connect(TouchedGlass12)

local function TouchedGlass13(hit)
    local partParent = hit.Parent
    local humanoid = partParent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        local num = Glass.Glass13
        num.Anchored = false
        num.BrickColor = BrickColor.Red()
        wait(2)
        num:Destroy()
    else return
    end
end

Glass.Glass13.Touched:Connect(TouchedGlass13)

local function TouchedGlass14(hit)
    local partParent = hit.Parent
    local humanoid = partParent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        local num = Glass.Glass14
        num.Anchored = false
        num.BrickColor = BrickColor.Red()
        wait(2)
        num:Destroy()
    else return
    end
end

Glass.Glass14.Touched:Connect(TouchedGlass14)

--then I'll do Glass2/1-8 which just turn the brick to green.

local function TouchedGlass21(hit)
    local partParent = hit.Parent
    local humanoid = partParent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        local num = Glass.Glass21
        num.BrickColor = BrickColor.Green()
    else return
    end
end

Glass.Glass21.Touched:Connect(TouchedGlass21)

local function TouchedGlass22(hit)
    local partParent = hit.Parent
    local humanoid = partParent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        local num = Glass.Glass22
        num.BrickColor = BrickColor.Green()
    else return
    end
end

Glass.Glass22.Touched:Connect(TouchedGlass22)

local function TouchedGlass23(hit)
    local partParent = hit.Parent
    local humanoid = partParent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        local num = Glass.Glass23
        num.BrickColor = BrickColor.Green()
    else return
    end
end

Glass.Glass23.Touched:Connect(TouchedGlass23)

local function TouchedGlass24(hit)
    local partParent = hit.Parent
    local humanoid = partParent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        local num = Glass.Glass24
        num.BrickColor = BrickColor.Green()
    else return
    end
end

Glass.Glass24.Touched:Connect(TouchedGlass24)

--Does anyone know a better way?
```

please note: there is 8 glasses in both "Glass2" and "Glass1" but I'll be adding more soon, that's why I'm looking for an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code it's pretty easy to spot that your using a **lot** of touched functions.

You can condense this significantly by using a for loop which iterates through each of the parts in script.Parent.

```
local glass = script.Parent

-- iterate through each child and assign the child to the variable object
for _, object in pairs(glass:GetChildren()) do
    -- Make sure this child of script.Parent is actually a part.
    if object:IsA("Part") then
        object.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
            local partParent = hit.Parent
            local humanoid = partParent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
            if humanoid then
                local num = object
                num.Anchored = false
                num.BrickColor = BrickColor.Red()
                wait(2)
                num:Destroy()
            end
        end)
    end
end
```

You also shouldn't need to have a return in your touched functions.

Comment: Thanks!
This helps a **lot** as I don't need to add millions of the functions :D